# C# regex: Combine a look ahead regex and a look behind regex into one

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to use regex to filter out files that don't use "\r\n" as line breaks. For example, if file contains a single "\n" or a single "\r", it will be filtered as disqualified file.

I've already found:

```
new Regex(@"(?<!\r)\n").Match(text).Success
```

This would tell me if the text has single "\n"

And:

```
new Regex(@"\r(?!\n)").Match(text).Success
```

This would tell me if the text has single "\r"

Currently I could write:

```
!(new Regex(@"(?<!\r)\n").Match(text).Success) && !(new Regex(@"\r(?!\n)").Match(text).Success)
```

But is there any way to combine the two into one ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Use alternation - `@"(?<!\r)\n|\r(?!\n)"`

Comment: This won't work as I tried file that contains both "\r\n" and "\r" as line breaks, it returns true. It needs to be returned false

Comment: Could anyone explain why it's downgraded ? I thought it's a meaningful question..

Comment: I think you want to return false if a file has \r\n. Just use `if (filecontents.Contains("\r\n")) return false;`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You're right, I confused myself for a moment, yes this @"(?<!\r)\n|\r(?!\n)"  solved my problem, I only need it to return false to get files only contain "\r\n" line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is you should never have a leading lookbehind assertion.
This adds up to a 10 times speed penalty depending on how big the text is
and how frequent the legitimate sequence is.

So if you lead off with a lookbehind assertion, it actually tests every character
twice, once for the assertion, and once for whats after it.
When in reality, you'd want to find the one after it first, which drops
a step and increases efficiency.

For this you can combine in an alternation.   `\n(?<!\r\n)|\r(?!\n)`

Comment: Thanks for the performance suggestion. It worked I will use this.